# finding minimum product value and return the multiplied values from matrix

Tags: matlab, combinations, minimum

For instance I have this matrices:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 2 12];

B = [5 4 3 2; 6 7 8 9; 10 9 1 7];

C = B.*A
```

the result is like this:

```
C = [5 8 9 8; 30 42 56 72; 90 90 2 84]
```

In my actual matrix the size of A and B varies.

My question is how do i find the minimum value from matrix C so the output will just be like this (from the result above):

```
C = 2
A = 2
B = 1
```

So basically, I need help with the code so matlab will find the minimum then return the value from matrices A and B that produce that minimum value.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second output argument of `min` returns the index.

```
[C, I] = min(C(:));
A = A(I);
B = B(I);
```

Note that if there are more than one element that are equal to minimum the first one in `C(:)` will be returned.

Comment: I believe 'I' will return a single value even if they say it is a vector. From matlab documentation "If there are several identical minimum values, the index of the first one found is returned".